# how to add a value in collection variable in For Each loop using UiPath without "Add to collection" Activity

Tags: uipath, rpa

How to add a value in the collection variable in For Each loop using UiPath without "Add to collection" Activity use Query

Comment: Is it an array, list or dictionary?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.